# How to embed mosmap google map into a non joomla webpage?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to embed google map on home page of my website.
I use the folowing code on my Joomla! site

```
mosmap msid='211583848080531580036.0004c74a22231f20dfa00'|lat='19.997023 '|lon='73.790102'|width='900'|height='650'|zoom='12'
```

How to get this code work in non-joomla site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps allows you to embed maps into a webpage by inserting a HTML snippet.
For more about embedding a Google Maps map into a page please visit https://support.google.com/maps/answer/72644

In your case, the HTML snippet would be something like this:

```
<iframe width="900" height="650" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://www.google.com/maps?q=19.997023,73.790102&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=19.996902,73.790102&amp;spn=0.104853,0.154324&amp;z=12&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with the Javascript tutorials that Google makes available..

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial